# event SOCKET_DATA does not receive all messages in AS3

Tags: sockets, actionscript, data-loss, message-loop

My AS3 client program does not receive all the data that was sent to it when sending a lot of messages. I do know its not my server causing this problem because all the messages are received and send correctly. My as3 client just does not receive all the data send.

```
    private function socketData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
       while(this.socket.bytesAvailable}
          var str:String = this.socket.readUTFBytes(this.socket.bytesAvailable);
          trace(str);
       }
    }
```

Does any of you know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I just had to open the port on my router.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue this afternoon. Finally i came with a solution:
In fact, you have to read the message byte by byte like so:

```
private function socketData (evt:ProgressEvent):void {
    var msg:String = ""; // create a buffer
    while (socket.bytesAvailable) { // while there is byte to read
        var byte:int = socket.readByte();
        if (byte==0) { // if we read the end byte
            trace(msg); // treat your message
            msg = ""; // free the buffer
        } else {
            msg += String.fromCharCode(byte); // else, we add the byte to our buffer
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, this helped but I still end up having data arriving with cuts to it (seems like I only receive half of the data in one of the cases.)